# Aggregation terms on field1 if value in field2

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting, aggregation

Let's inject some sample data:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dt/art/1 -d '{ "basket1": ["banana","apple", "peach"], 
                                         "basket2": ["banana", "orange"]}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dt/art/2 -d '{ "basket1":["orange", "apple"],
                                         "basket2":[]}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dt/art/3 -d '{ "basket1": ["apple"],
                                         "basket2": ["apple", "banana"]}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dt/art/4 -d '{ "basket1:["banana"],
                                         "basket2": ["banana"]}'
```

I need to find number of article where 'banana' was found in basket1 but not basket2. and to repeat that for all values in basket1.
For example, I would expect here:

```
banana : 0
apple: 2
peach: 1
orange: 1
```

So far the only solution I found doing so is through a sub-aggregation :

```
body = {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}},
        "aggs": {
            "basket1_count": {
                "terms":{
                    "field": basket1},
                "aggs": {
                    "basket2_count": {
                        "terms":{
                            "field": basket2,
                            "size": 10000}}}}}}
```

Then I would the rest in python. (difference between number of doc where value in field 1 found and number of doc where value in field2 found)

Is there any better way to do that ?